# Telnet connection not writing tab to a file

Tags: c#, unix

I have a C# WPF application that is making a Telnet connection to write some content to a file on a Linux system from a Windows system. So say I have some text like this.

> Here is a bit\tof text \r\n Followed by a new line.

Here is generally how the code goes:

```
string ipAddress = "11.11.11.11";
int port = 66;
TelnetConnection tc = new TelnetConnection(ipAddress, port);
string s = tc.Login("root", "password", 100);
string prompt = s.TrimEnd();
if (prompt != "$" && prompt != "#"){
    throw new Exception("Connection failed");
}
tc.WriteLine("echo $'Here is a bit\tof text \r\n Followed by a new line.' >> MyFile.txt");
```

Here is the TelnetConnection class I use:\

```
enum Verbs
{
    WILL = 251,
    WONT = 252,
    DO = 253,
    DONT = 254,
    IAC = 255
}

enum Options
{
    SGA = 3
}

class TelnetConnection
{
    TcpClient tcpSocket;

    int TimeOutMs = 10;

    public TelnetConnection(string Hostname, int Port)
    {
        tcpSocket = new TcpClient(Hostname, Port);

    }

    public string Login(string Username, string Password, int LoginTimeOutMs)
    {
        int oldTimeOutMs = TimeOutMs;
        TimeOutMs = LoginTimeOutMs;
        string s = Read();
        if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
            throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no login prompt");
        WriteLine(Username);

        s += Read();
        if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
            throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no password prompt");
        WriteLine(Password);

        s += Read();
        TimeOutMs = oldTimeOutMs;
        return s;
    }

    public void WriteLine(string cmd)
    {
        Write(cmd + "\n");
    }

    public void Write(string cmd)
    {
        if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return;
        byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Replace("\0xFF", "\0xFF\0xFF"));
        tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    public string Read()
    {
        if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            ParseTelnet(sb);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
        } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get { return tcpSocket.Connected; }
    }

    void ParseTelnet(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        while (tcpSocket.Available > 0)
        {
            int input = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
            switch (input)
            {
                case -1:
                    break;
                case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                    // interpret as command
                    int inputverb = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                    if (inputverb == -1) break;
                    switch (inputverb)
                    {
                        case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                            //literal IAC = 255 escaped, so append char 255 to string
                            sb.Append(inputverb);
                            break;
                        case (int)Verbs.DO:
                        case (int)Verbs.DONT:
                        case (int)Verbs.WILL:
                        case (int)Verbs.WONT:
                            // reply to all commands with "WONT", unless it is SGA (suppres go ahead)
                            int inputoption = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                            if (inputoption == -1) break;
                            tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Verbs.IAC);
                            if (inputoption == (int)Options.SGA)
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WILL : (byte)Verbs.DO);
                            else
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WONT : (byte)Verbs.DONT);
                            tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)inputoption);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    sb.Append((char)input);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to check the file the it is written to like this

> Here is a bitof text 
> Followed by a new line.

So the tab character isn't even read, but the new line is for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: is that  a commercial TelnetConnection library?

Comment: All looks ok, how do you verify the tab isn't there?

Comment: Update: Added the TelnetConnection, apologies @pm100.

Comment: @orhtej2 I checked the file where it was uploaded and the tab characters were not in the file, which resulted in the file not quite being parsed correctly by the thing I am using it for.

Comment: What's the shell running on remote host? Is `$'\t'` a valid way to echo tab character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is given by @Johannes Krackowizer but the explanation is missing a detail: the 'TelnetConnection' isn't a file. What you are doing is typing to the remote computer. @Greg M also mentions this.

When you send `\t` in your string, you are sending a literal `<tab>` character. The computer at the other end is trying to finish typing a file name for you because that's what happens when you hit `<tab>`. If you want to get a tab back you need to send a `\` and a `t`. The `t` you can just send, but the `\` needs to be sent as `\\` because `\` is an escape character, as you know. So send:

```
"echo $'Here is a bit\\tof text \r\n Followed by a new line.' >> MyFile.txt"
```

Note the `bit\\tof` with two backslashes. So why does `\r\n` work? Because it's `<Enter>` and `<Ctrl>+<Enter>`, and the string you are *typing* is being typed within single quotes. When you use single quotes you can hit `<Enter>` and keep typing until you are done and end with the final `'`.

As others have mentioned, `printf` is generally preferred:

```
"printf $'Here is a bit\\tof text \r\n Followed by a new line.\n' >> MyFile.txt"
```

Next, in your code, the backslash should also be escaped, so you probably need to escape those characters as well:

```
tc.WriteLine("printf $'Here is a bit\\\\tof text \\r\\n Followed by a new line.\\n' >> MyFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what system you are connection to and what shell is running there but you probably need to double escape tab so it's not only `\t` but `\\t` so that a `\` and a `t` is sent to the shell. But then you need to enable the echo command to interpret the `\t` not as string but as escaped  thats done with the `-e` switch in bash. At least in bash that should look like this.

```
tc.WriteLine("echo -e \"Here is a bit\\tof text \\r\\n Followed by a new line.\" >> MyFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple and is not telnet specific.

Open up Powershell or Cmd and try typing your string and you will see.

command lines interpret tab as either a command complete (auto-complete closest match ex.  '>ec\t' will produce '>echo'), move to next field or throws the tab away.

you need to replace '\t' (for this particular use) with spaces.

Tabs CAN generally be sent over telnet.  I do it all the time.  usually the server interprets it as a request to move to next field.

For example 'MyName\tpassword' will fill in first field with MyName and then move to next field and fill with password

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf` that would be more predictable

```
tc.WriteLine("printf 'Here is a bit\tof text \r\n Followed by a new line.\n'  >> MyFile.txt");
```

You can also use `xxd` (or similar) to verify the content

```
printf 'Here is a bit\tof text \r\n Followed by a new line.\n' | xxd
00000000: 4865 7265 2069 7320 6120 6269 7409 6f66  Here is a bit.of
00000010: 2074 6578 7420 0d0a 2046 6f6c 6c6f 7765   text .. Followe
00000020: 6420 6279 2061 206e 6577 206c 696e 652e  d by a new line.
00000030: 0a                                       .
```